# Can time dilation occur between entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, time-dilation

If two particles are entangled, with one moving near the speed of light relative to the other, would observing one tell us something about the other in the other's future or past?

Comment: In the classical [EPR experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox#Description_of_the_paradox) we have two photons moving even *at* the speed of light relative to each other, in the opposite directions. So measuring the momentum of one tells us the momentum of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a simple example, the decay of a pi0 to two photons. These photons are entangled because the pi0 has spin 0 whereas a photon has spin one, so one must have spin projection parallel to its motion and the other antiparallel.

One of the two gammas goes off to the moon, the other is detected in the lab and its spin measured. If it is +1 we immediately know that the one that went to the moon had spin -1. Time does not enter the problem  because the lab is at rest.

Take a Z0 to μ+μ- . The same spin argument holds and again time does not affect the outcome, measuring the charge of the one in the lab, tells us what the charge of the one that went to the moon is, in addition to the knowledge of spin orientation, because it should add up to 1, the spin of the Z0.

Answer (score 0):

To determine that the particles were entangled, you need to measure both of them, and then compare the results of the measurements. You would then indeed potentially find that the measurements were superluminally correlated.

However, in order to compare the results, and realize they were correlated, you need to be in the forward light cone of *both* particles. Therefore no superluminal communication is possible. This is true independently of the particles' relative speeds.

Comment: We find that the measurements are correlated, we do not *find* that they are superluminally correlated. That can only be *inferred* from violations of [Bell inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem#Bell_inequalities), *if* one assumes that they were supposed to hold in the first place. But that assumption is only justified under classical "local realism" about quantum particles, so the inference is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Time dilation is relative to velocity as they approach the speed of light... by contrast only EM spectrum as associated via the photon. Quantum entanglement moves faster than light at least as explainedby Kako. If I have two electrons close together, they perhaps would oscillate in sequence then according to the quantum theory currently established If I then separate them, an invisible cohesion will have emerged which connects them regardless of distance.. if said two electrons, even separated away by lightyears, if one were to tamper or play with one electron, then the other electron “detects” this vibration immediately.  Think of a very long rope be it 5 yards or five miles long.... if  I were to tug on it the entirety would move, not necessarily faster than the speed of light just it's observed no matter where along the rope you happen to be. Cohesiveness on quantum level. We still don't understand Standard Model physics...accurately enough because new particles emerge in experiments. Unknown disclosed particles may function as carriers for entanglement. This may also serve to explain the fundamental forces of gravity which has little bearing on quantum level. According to sources quantum mechanics regards time as universal and absolute, whereas general relativity regards the flow of time as malleable and relative. In any scenario time may be manipulative in a discussion regards to scale.